# Why am I getting empty value from mongoDB if this nodejs rest api is ok and its mongoose structure and mongodb data?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

This API gets a request param, which is filtered and passed to an User mongoose model like shown in code below, is querying mongodb and returning empty. Why is it happening if everything is ok?

```
routes.route('/user')
    .get( (req,res) => {
        //const query = req.query;
        //const {query} = req;
        const {query} = req;
        
        if (req.query.UserName){
            query.UserName = req.query.UserName;
            console.log("ok 2 " + query.UserName);
        }      

        User.find({UserName:query.UserName}, (err, data)=> {
            if (err){
                console.log("not ok");
                return res.send(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("ok: " + data);                
                return res.json(data);
            }
            
        });
    });
```

For testing my API, i use postman or webbrowser using this URL:
http://localhost:4000/api/user?UserName=smed

When checking log, you can see that it prints the parameter and the data with empty value, too.

This is the mongoose model:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let UserSchema = new Schema({
    UserId: {
        type: Number
    },
    PersonId: {
        type: Number
    },
    UserName: {
        type: String,
        unique: true
    },
    Deactivated: {
        type: Boolean
    },
    Password: {
        type: String
    },
    SysCreationDate: {
        type: Date
    },
    LastLoginDate: {
        type: Date
    }

},{collection:'User'});

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', UserSchema);
```

And the data in mongo:

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d1037acde2b6feb37938db6"},"User":[{"UserId":
{"$numberInt":"1"},"PersonId":{"$numberInt":"1"},"UserName":"smed","Deactivated":false,"Password":"1234","SysCreationDate":"2016-06-23T21:42:31+07:00"},{"UserId":{"$numberInt":"2"},"PersonId":{"$numberInt":"2"},"UserName":"eper","Deactivated":false,"Password":"1234","SysCreationDate":"2016-06-23T22:42:31+07:00"}]}
```

i have tested this in a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.x.x machine, and i get the same error.
These are my dependencies:

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.19.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.6.2"
  }
```

And NodeJS: v8.10.0

Response is empty array in json. It should query User collection and return the object contained when UserName property is "smed", the parameter that is sent within the request:
http://localhost:4000/api/user?UserName=smed

It should return mongo data (shown before) when UserName=smed

```
{"_id":{"$oid":"5d1037acde2b6feb37938db6"},"User":[{"UserId":{"$numberInt":"1"},"PersonId":{"$numberInt":"1"},"UserName":"smed","Deactivated":false,"Password":"1234","SysCreationDate":"2016-06-23T21:42:31+07:00"}]}
```

Comment: `find` won't error if it's not able to find documents, so you're seeing that your search query isn't correctly formatted, so it's not matching any documents. Take a look at the document that you posted: UserName isn't a top level field

Comment: Thank you, but UserName is one of the properties of the collection User, so, it is not at 2nd level, because it is not nested on another property.

Answer (score 0):

seems like you are doing the wrong query, try with the following code:

```
routes.route('/user').get((req, res) => {
    const query = (req.query.userName) ? {
        User: {
            $elemMatch: {
                $eq: req.query.userName
            }
        }
    } : {};
    User.find(query, (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error is: ", err);
            return res.send(err);
        } else {
            console.log("Data is: " + data);
            return res.json(data);
        }

    });
});
```

or with the es6 async/await:

```
routes.route('/user').get(async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const query = (req.query.userName) ? {
            User: {
                $elemMatch: {
                    $eq: req.query.userName
                }
            }
        } : {};
        const data = await User.find(query).lean();
        console.log("Data is: " + data);
        return res.json(data);
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("Error is: ", err);
        return res.send(err);
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I am getting no data :(

Comment: can you share your collection schema?

Comment: Sure, here you are the link (User structure and User data in mongoDB and the function that query the param into the DB): https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OxZ9C9mdrut4I0bDgQPMXvWCXSrzGtwv?usp=sharing

Comment: the structure of data in your collection and your schema is not same.. how did you insert that data??

Comment: What is the difference between the collection and schema? (They are written exactly, taking care of each upper/lower case for each property). Rergading to how i inserted the data? I inserted them using mongoimport for a domain data i created in a json file and that is the data imported in the database.

Comment: **Schema** is the structure of your document, where you define the types and other constraints of fields, which is used to create mongoose model. On the other hand **Collections** in mongo are something in which the documents are stored (like tables in SQL db's)... In the above case, your schema is straight forward and contains, 'userName' key at the root level, where as in existing data, the same key is present in the objects which are inside the **User** array key. Either the data you have in your collections is false, or you may need to change your schema

Comment: thanks, do you have a Documentation where i could face the error?

Comment: Well i'd recommend you to go through the official mongoose docs: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/documents.html Also you can try changing your schema like this `let UserSchema = new Schema({User: [{UserId: {type: Number},PersonId: {type: Number},UserName: {type: String, unique: true},Deactivated: {type: Boolean},Password: {type: String},SysCreationDate: {type: Date},LastLoginDate: {type: Date}}]}, { collection: 'User' });`